# Random question about expectation and moments

Tags: probability-theory

Okay, consider a random variable $X$. Suppose that we know, that its expectation $\mathbb{E}(X)=1$. Now I know that, since its first moment exists, higher moments exist as well. Now is it possible, to compute $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$ just with the information above?

Comment: Unfortunately, the existence of $\mathbb{E}[X]$ does not imply the existence of higher moments.

Comment: And even if higher moments do exist, none of them is determined by the value of the first moment. Actually the question is rather surprising since it is well known, even by practitioners of statistics that are not mathematicians, that the mean does not suffice to determine the variance, already for example in the gaussian case.

Comment: You would need $\mathbb{Var}(X)$ to find $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$ from $\mathbb{E}(X)$.